# Why is SSO not working correctly for Azure AD B2C custom policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, msal.js

We are currently using Azure B2C for authentication with a React.js app.  The library we are using is msal.js.

Initially, we were using a standard user flow with SSO enabled, and the msaljs library worked correctly (and still does).  In that application flow, the first call to B2C would ask for an id_token, and then initiate a second call in an iframe that automatically worked because the user was already signed in.  This would all happen automatically, and the user would just see themselves being logged in without any issues.  In this case the call to authenticate in the iframe returns a 302 back to our app with the access_token for accessing our API.

We have now switched to a custom policy in order to customise the login page and use javascript.  This has been setup using custom policies and works correctly with multi factor authentication for logging in.  The flow works as follows:

- The first call msal.js makes to B2C (/authorize) calls requests an id_token, and follows the flow correctly to log the user in.
- The second call to B2C (/authorize) is done in an iframe as well, but instead of returning a 302, it returns a 200, which then (correctly) fails to render because the header sent from B2C includes the X-Frame-Options:deny header
- MSAL waits for 6 seconds for the iframe to return, and because it does not, then initiates a redirect to the login page for the access token, which works, but requires the user to log in twice.

This is all happening (I presume) because SSO is not working correctly with the custom policy.  In the first scenario with a user flow from B2C, the SSO kicks in and automatically redirects the user back to the app with the access token, in the second, because SSO is not working, the user has to login twice.

My custom policy looks as follows, built off the samples provided in the (very sparse) documentation for custom policies with B2C:

- A technical profile exists and looks like the following:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SM-AAD">
  <DisplayName>Session Mananagement Provider</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.SSO.DefaultSSOSessionProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <PersistedClaims>
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" />
  </PersistedClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectIdFromSession" DefaultValue="true"/>
  </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

- Each of the technical profiles that are used for reading and writing information to the directory reference this technical profile, eg.

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
  ...
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

- In my profile file (SignUpOfSignIn.xml) I have the following under `RelyingParty`

```xml
<UserJourneyBehaviors>
  <SingleSignOn Scope="Tenant" KeepAliveInDays="7" />
  <SessionExpiryType>Absolute</SessionExpiryType>
  <SessionExpiryInSeconds>1200</SessionExpiryInSeconds>
  <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
</UserJourneyBehaviors>
```

- In my UserJourney for that custom policy, each orchestration step refers to a TechnicalProfile that includes the SM-AAD TechnicalProfile for Session management, except the PhoneFactor (which uses it's own SM-MFA technical profile that sets isActiveMfaSession to true)

Despite all this, I cannot get SSO to work correctly with the custom profile.  One thing I noticed is that the ClaimType "objectIdFromSession" which is part of the SSO profile is not used.  I would have thought that would be used to determine if an orchestration step should be skipped, is that correct?

Any other help or hints as to what might be wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: quick question, are you trying with MFA enabled? if yes, can you try same scenario and without MFA and check?

Comment: Yes, looks like that is a contributing factor.  Looks like the isActiveMfaSession isn't set to true.  If I use objectIdFromSession as a precursor to skip the MFA step, it also works correctly.

Comment: I think there is a bug in the SM-MFA TP. Try change Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber to strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT do you still consider this a bug? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L1105 the lastest version of the file still references Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber. Since isActiveMFASession is always false when reloading the user from the SSO session, what claim should we use to skip MFA / password reset ... in this specific case?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I am facing the same

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem  and was using MFA Custom Policies. I resolved the problem by changing the SM from the PhoneFactor. From `TRUSTFRAMEWORKBASE.xml`, I took the SM-MFA profile and put it in the SM-AAD profile.

```xml
    <TechnicalProfile Id="SM-MFA">
          <DisplayName>Session Mananagement Provider</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.SSO.DefaultSSOSessionProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <PersistedClaims>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
          </PersistedClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isActiveMFASession" DefaultValue="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
```

SM-AAD profile :

```xml
    <TechnicalProfile Id="SM-AAD">
          <DisplayName>Session Mananagement Provider</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.SSO.DefaultSSOSessionProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <PersistedClaims>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" />
            <!--Claim from SM-MFA-->
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
          </PersistedClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectIdFromSession" DefaultValue="true" />
            <!--Claim from SM-MFA-->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isActiveMFASession" DefaultValue="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Then I changed all the profiles to reference only SM-AAD.